# Assign one list with variables to other list with data

Tags: python

I want to assign folder names on `dirs` list to variables from `vars` list. Main problem is that `var` have stable number of items, but `dirs` can be changed by user.

```
import os, sys
path = "C:\BAR_PREK"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
vars = ['VAR0.Value', 'VAR1.Value', 'VAR1.Value', 'VAR3.Value', 'VAR4.Value', 'VAR5.Value', 'VAR6.Value']
```

I was written stupid code like this:

```
VAR0.Value = dirs[0]
VAR1.Value = dirs[1]
VAR2.Value = dirs[2]
<...>
```

But if we get empty dirs[x] value, it causes an error.

Comment: What do you mean stable number of items? Update your question what your expected output

Comment: I believe they mean that `len(vars)` is constant.

Comment: See how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What are `VAR0`, `VAR1`, `VAR2`, etc.?

Comment: Sorry for my imperfect problem description. i just want to assign folder names to nine variables (VAR1, VAR2 etc). My main problem is that folders count can be changed from 1 to 9 by user and i should assign 5 or 6 ar 3 values to 9 variables. First of them will get values, others will not . These variables is local variabels from Nicelabel 2017 powerforms it needs to name buttons with folder names.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand it correctly. You can first get the shortest length of dirs and vars, then assign the values. Like this:

```
import os
path = "C:\BAR_PREK"
dirs = os.listdir(path)
vars = ['VAR0.Value', 'VAR1.Value', 'VAR1.Value', 'VAR3.Value', 'VAR4.Value','VAR5.Value', 'VAR6.Value']

num = min([len(dirs),len(vars)])
for i in range(num):
    vars[i] = dirs[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec for the job

```
In [116]: vars = ['VAR0.Value', 'VAR1.Value', 'VAR1.Value', 'VAR3.Value', 'VAR4.Value','VAR5.Value', 'VAR6.Value']

In [117]: for idx, var in enumerate(vars):
     ...:     exec("DIR{}='{}'".format(idx, var))
     ...:

In [118]: DIR0
Out[118]: 'VAR0.Value'

In [119]: DIR1
Out[119]: 'VAR1.Value'
```